# How to loop 'Text To Column' code using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to figure out how to loop Text to Column codes.

Hoping to get it to loop until the last data or maybe empty row/cells.

I may have more than 60 list of materials though.

```vb
'Material 1
Range("A2").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(65, 1)), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A3").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(40, 1), _
Array(43, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A4").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O2"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(26, 1), Array(63, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
  :=True

'Material 2
Range("A5").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B5"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(65, 1)), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A6").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F5"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(40, 1), _
  Array(43, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A7").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O5"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(26, 1), Array(63, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
  :=True

'Material 3
Range("A8").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B8"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(65, 1)), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A9").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("F8"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(40, 1), _
  Array(43, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Range("A10").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("O8"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
  FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(26, 1), Array(63, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
  :=True
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this, but I am not sure how efficient my codes are or if there is a better way.

```vb
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim p As Long

LastRowA = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Looping first line starting Range A2
For i = 2 To LastRowA Step 3 'step 3 to count every 3rd row
    Cells(i, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(i, 2), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(65, 1)), _
      TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next i

'Looping second line Range A3
For j = 3 To LastRowA Step 3
    Cells(j, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(j - 1, 6), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(40, 1), _
      Array(43, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(73, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
Next j

'Looping third line Range A4
For p = 4 To LastRowA Step 3
    Cells(p, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(p - 2, 15), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
      FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(26, 1), Array(63, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
      :=True
Next p
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's pretty clunky, but should follow the pattern of looping through a column of data and performing a TextToColumn transformation based on which of the three rows in each section the loop is currently in.

Here's the pseudo-code logic, based on your example:

1. If in row 1 output to column "B"
2. If in row 2 output to column "F"
3. If in row 3 output to column "O"... repeat steps 1-3 for each section

Here's the VBA:

```
Sub TextToColumnLoop()

    'Set up the variables
    Dim DataCol As String
    Dim Row1Col, Row2Col, Row3Col As String
    Dim FirstRow, LastRow As Integer
    Dim ctr As Integer

    'Your variables (change these to whatever you want)
    '--This enables you to re-use this code and apply it to different data ranges
    DataCol = "A"   '= the column where your data is
    Row1Col = "B"   '= the column where you want the row 1 data outputted
    Row2Col = "F"   '= the column where you want the row 2 data outputted
    Row3Col = "O"   '= the column where you want the row 3 data outputted
    FirstRow = 2    '= cell "A2" in this example
    LastRow = 10    '= cell "A10" in this example --**NOTE:use this to statically set the last row
    ctr = 1         'start on row "1" of the current section

    '**NOTE: Use this while loop to dynamically set the last row in your range (as opposed to the var being set statically, above)
    'While loop to find the active range (loops as long as the cells aren't empty)
    i = FirstRow
    While Me.Range(DataCol & i) <> ""
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    'Set the last non-empty cell as the last cell in the range
    LastRow = i - 1

    'Loop through your rows
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow

        If ctr = 1 Then

            'TextToColumn for Row 1
            Me.Range(DataCol & i).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range(Row1Col & i), _
                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(65, 1)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

            'Increment row counter
            ctr = ctr + 1

        ElseIf ctr = 2 Then

            'TextToColumn for Row 2
            Me.Range(DataCol & i).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range(Row2Col & i), _
                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(37, 1), _
                    Array(40, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(54, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(73, 1)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

            'Increment row counter
            ctr = ctr + 1

        ElseIf ctr = 3 Then

            'TextToColumn for the Row 3
            Me.Range(DataCol & i).TextToColumns _
            Destination:=Range(Row3Col & i), _
                DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(26, 1), Array(63, 1)), _
                TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

            'Reset row counter
            ctr = 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Make sure you place this code in the worksheet object in the VBEditor for the worksheet that has your data. Do **not** put this code in a module, since it uses the *Me.Range()* (i.e., where "Me" = current worksheet) syntax, as opposed to *Sheets("Sheet1").Range()* where the worksheet name is explicitly named.

If you're confused about what I mean when I say "worksheet object" vs. "module", then check out a screenshot **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Dg2.png)**

Comment: thanks for the help! appreciate it alot. will try this codes soon and let you know on the outcome. and will check out the screenshot too.

Answer (score 0):

The below code Loops text to columns for any size data set.

```
 Sub TextToColumns()

'Deines Last Row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = 1048576 'the last row possible in excel
    'optional alternative **LastRow** Code
       'Counts number of rows (counts from last row of Column A):
         'Dim LastRow As Long
         'LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Counts number of Columns (my headers start in row 1)
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Loops Text to columns
    Dim StartingRow, StaringColumn As Long
    StartingRow = 1

    For StartingColumn = 1 To LastColumn
        Range(Cells(StartingRow, StartingColumn), Cells(LastRow, StartingColumn)).Select

        Selection.TextToColumns , DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Next

End Sub
```